# How to tighten an optical fiber to the wall?

Tags: walls

I would like to lengthen my optical fiber so I can put my Internet box on a proper shelf. That's quite easy, I'll just have to buy a longer fiber.

The problem is that I don't want it to hang everywhere ! What is the best way to tighten a cable (well an optical fiber in my case) against the wall ? I want it to be discrete, and I want it to hold.

Comment: Be very careful - depending on the particular fiber you have, optical fiber can object strongly to being bent too much/too sharply. If you are buying a new patch cord, be sure to get one that is "reduced bend radius" to limit your exposure to this problem, which tends not to be obvious to folks used to dealing with wire, not fiber. Also be sure to get the correct type of fiber and connectors to match what you have.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [surface mount wire mold](https://www.zoro.com/legrand-raceway-series-500-10-ft-ivory-v500/i/G0336682/?gclid=CL7a2sPr5s0CFVFgfgod7ycDQg&gclsrc=aw.ds) like this or a stick on one. It would protect the fiber and look better than sticking a wire on the wall. Make sure not to bend the fiber two tightly or it will break.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need. How do you mount it on the wall ? It may seem like a stupid question, but I'm new to all of this ! :P

Comment: There some that have double stick tape and some that use Sheetrock screws, I think I saw a hole in the back on the linked one so it would use a screw, pop the top off screw or tape to the wall. Put the cable in the tray and snap back together, there are plastic and metal types plastic types may be easier to cut than metal depending on what tools you have available, good luck

Comment: Thanks ! I think I will go with one with the double stick tape.